# GMail Username and Password not accepted error when sending email with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I get the following error when trying to use my GMail account to send an email from my [PHP application](http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/) with SwiftMailer.

```
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted
```

This is my SwiftMailer code:

```
$transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername('ayrshireminiscontact@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('~password-in-here~');

$mailer  = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Portfolio Enquiry')
    ->setFrom(array('ayrshireminiscontact@gmail.com' => 'CRMPicco Portfolio Enquiry'))
    ->setTo(array('picco@crmpicco.co.uk' => 'A name'))
    ->setBody($email_body);

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

This is the entry in my Apache error log and the stack trace.

> [Wed Aug 18 22:06:10.284728 2015] [:error] [pid 9298] [client
>   10.0.0.1:64806] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250
>   but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not
>   accepted. Learn more at\r\n535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 gj13sm2191931wic.22 -
>   gsmtp\r\n"' in
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('535-5.7.8
>   Usern...', Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(243):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n',
>   Array, Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/Auth/XOAuth2Authenticator.php(54):
>   Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n',
>   Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php(176):
>   Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_XOAuth2Authent in
>   /var/www/portfolio/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 383, referer: https://crmpicco.dev/

I have tried http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and I can log in to the account through a web browser without any problems.

This happens on my local development machine and the publically-accesible site. Is this an issue with my GMail account or my implementation?

Comment: Did you enable Allow less secure apps access?

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, that fixed my error on my local environment. Feel free to submit this as an answer and i'll happily accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [allow access from less-secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en), because IMAP via password is fundamentally insecure. (it's non-revocable)

Better yet, switch to OAuth authentication.